# Listview android padding

Tags: android, nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-telerik-ui

Is somehow possible to disable padding in ListView on Android? On iOS is everything good and there is no padding. On Android you can see padding around the Label.

There is testing playground with problem https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=sdr0VD

[image: iOS]
[image: android]

Comment: which tns version did you use? I tested your code with tns@6.1.2 and android 9 and have not observed this bug.

Comment: yes it is possible, please share your code so we can see what is your code problem or what you'll need to add sir.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a issue with theme **v2.2.0** (latest as of today), removing the core theme should solve the issue. Another workaround is,

**Step 1:** Wrap your Label with GridLayout

```
    <ng-template nsTemplateKey="heading" let-item="item">
        <GridLayout>
            <Label text="Test text" class="heading"></Label>
        </GridLayout>
    </ng-template>
```

**Step 2:** Add below CSS

```
ListView > * {
    padding:  0;
}
```